# How to read JSONObject in dojo, where JSONObject is created in JSP?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to read JSONObject in dojo?

I have a JSONObject in my jsp.

```
JSONObject  myJSONObj = new JSONObject();
```

How can I read this `myJSONObj` in my dojo or *.js file, in `'onload function'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might want to try this:

```
window.load = function(){
 var myjson = <%= getJSON() %>
 //using myjson
}
```

getJSON is a function which returns myJSONObj as JSON formatted String

update:
short example. hope it helps

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<%
class Foor{
    public String getJSON(){
        return "{foo:'bar'}";
    }
}

Foor myfoo = new Foor();

%>
<script language=javascript>
var myjson = <%= myfoo.getJSON()%>
alert(myjson.foo);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @jebberwocky: I tried this, but it gives me "illegal XML character" error.

Comment: Since the output of "myfoo.getJSON()" will be considered a string within the script tag you should wrap it like this:

var myjson = dojo.fromJson('<%= myfoo.getJSON() %>');

and I think that example will work...

Comment: @subhaze, if I am creating instance of Foor class 'myfoo' in my JSP,then will myfoo is accessible in dojo (js file). I tried this also. But whenever I say var **myjson = dojo.fromJson('<%= myfoo.getJSON() %>');** then code doesnot get compiled even. Kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: I've not worked with JSP before but with PHP that's how I've done it. If your code is similar to above where you mix server-side code with HTML then I would think you're instance of Foor class 'myfoo' should work as stated above with the modification of using the dojo.fromJson to make sure it's valid JSON as {foo:'bar'} is not. http://pastebin.com/bL9s9xYa That's about all I can think of sorry :/

Comment: Maybe just try separating it all out. A page that is strictly JSP that outputs JSON and an HTML file that does an AJAX request for that JSON...

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the output in the [toJson](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/toJson) function.

For running it when the DOM is ready try [addOnLoad](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/addOnLoad)

And if you're wanting to load it via AJAX onLoad try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/cBk4T/)

[EDIT]

It just dawned on me that I put "toJson" it should be [fromJson](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/fromJson) since you're needing to convert a JSON string to a JSON object. Here is an example [dojo: json string to json object](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Sa5Uw/)

Comment: My major concern is how can I retrieve myJSONObj  object in dojo, as I am creating and setting in JSP. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.